# Parsing numbers in a text using regexp MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab

In a cell string in MATLAB, I have a string which looks like this:

```
 A = {'... "precision": 0.01254,"recall": 0.2154, ... ,"precision": 0.01324,"recall": 0.25454 ... '}
```

where ... implies different words. I want to parse this text and read all the numbers in front of the words "precision" and "recall". I have thought about using `regexp()` for this purpose. Any idea how to use it properly?
Thanks

Comment: I am not sure how your data looks like, is this a cell containing only one element? So `numel(A)` is 1? Try `textscan`, setting `,` and `:` to be delimiters. `regexp` is also possible but a bit more complicated to understand.

Comment: In what format are you expecting the output ? Is it only numerical value ? I suppose you wish to extract something like `"precision": 0.01254` and `"recall":0.2154`.

Comment: I would suggest do it in separate steps to get precision and recall `regexp(A,'"precision":\s(\d*\.\d*)','tokens')` and `regexp(A,'"recall":\s(\d*\.\d*)','tokens')`

Comment: @RandomGuy: It can be combined using `alteration` i.e `|`. Why go for separate steps ?

Comment: Or if you want to keep the precisions and recall together you could use : `regexp(A,'"precision":\s(\d*\.\d*),"recall":\s(\d*\.\d*)','tokens')`  https://regex101.com/r/mD3xI3/1

Comment: Random Guy, thanks it seem to be working very well using regexp(). What is the role of `\d*\.\d* ` in your regexp() ?

Comment: @Yas: I suggest you should use `(?:"precision":|"recall":)(?:\s+)?(?:\d*\.\d*)` because more or less it boils down to matching those two strings. Do it in 1 step or 2. 1 is more concise than 2. All your choice mate.

Comment: `\d*\.\d*` matches any number written with a decimal point, now thinking about it `\d*\.?\d*` is the correct way to do it. If you look at the explanation section of the regex link I posted it has human readable interpretation of the regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract `"precision": 0.01254` and `"recall":0.2154` from that long string, I would use something like this.

**Regex:** `("precision":|"recall":)(?:\s+)?(?:\d*\.\d*)`

**Flags used:**

- `g` for global search.

**Explanation:**

- `("precision":|"recall":)` : This part searches for `precision` **OR** `recall`.
- `(?:\s+)?(?:\d*\.\d*)` : This part looks for `numerical data`.

<kbd>**[Regex101 demo here.](https://regex101.com/r/qI2pL8/1)**</kbd>

**Edit #1:**

As OP mentioned in one comment that **sometimes** number is in format `2.8621e-6`, we only need to capture the `e-6` part and make it optional. Resultant regex will be as follows.

**Regex:** `("precision":|"recall":)(?:\s+)?(?:\d*\.\d*(?:e-\d*)?)`

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo for format of this type `2.8621e-6`](https://regex101.com/r/qI2pL8/3)**</kbd>

Comment: What if one fine day there is no recall for a precision, or the other way. How will one correlate which one corresponds to which ? Also, why are you capturing the strings precision and recall instead of the numbers ?

Comment: @noob thanks alot for clarifying the answer. It certainly has helped. I think the response of @Random Guy was good. `regexp(A,'"precision":\s(\d*\.?\d*)','tokens')` works pretty well for capturing numbers in front of the word precision.

Comment: @RandomGuy and @Yas : I don't know much about `Matlab`. I tried to provide a solution from `regex` point of view.

Comment: You did it great noob ! Thank you

Comment: Guys, a big issue, sometimes my number is in the format `2.8621e-6` and using `regexp(A,'"precision":\s(\d*\.?\d*)','tokens')` doesn't capture the number well. How can I fix this ?

Comment: @Yas: To accommodate the `exponential` part we will have to capture `e-6` optionally. Check updated answer.